# How does Android 6 full encryption work ... when it doesn't ask for the password at start time?

Tags: encryption, android

I am using an Samsung S7 edge; together with IBM Maas360; and I ran into a an interesting situation.

Prior last week, my S7 was running Android 6.

Android can be configured to ask for your password **before** the system starts. By default, the device will start the OS, and later on, when the OS is up and running ask first for PIN; then for your Android password.

Anyway, last week Maas360 recognized my device to have an "encryption status" of `active`.

Then I received the long awaited upgrade to Android 7. Everything works nicely ... but the next morning, upon restarting the device ... I realize at some point that I lost the Wifi certificates for my companies intranet. Why? Because now, Maas sees "encryption status" as `unknown`.

I then turned into the settings; and changed the device to ask for the password directly after start. I restart ... and as expected - I am asked for the password, and then there is this "unlock" icon indicating that my device gets "unlocked" during OS startup. Checking encryption status again; I now get `active`. (which will hopefully fix my Maas/wifi certificate problem)

But beyond that; I am pretty **confused** by now: why can Android 6 give me "encryption is active"; although the OS starts up without my password? How can it decrypt  all the encrypted data ... when it doesn't have my password?

( for the record: I used this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchboarder.android.api.demos) to actually check the encryption status of the device )

Answer (score 1):

The method of encryption [changed in Android 7 (Nougat)](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/11/24/android-n-encryption/).

In previous versions of Android, the OS used a simplistic full-disk encryption scheme, similar to that common for desktop and laptop computers. This required a password at boot to be able to access pretty much anything. A side effect was that the phone had to keep everything decrypted while the phone was locked, or else it couldn't do normal smartphone functions like receive push notifications.

This was a pretty major problem, so in Android 7 Google changed Android to use a more sophisticated (but still less sophisticated than iOS's) encryption system, in which files that are determined to be sensitive are individually encrypted. The effect you'll see as a user is that certain things will now work from a boot before you've given the OS the information necessary to derive your encryption key.

Comment: I understand that A7 introduced a different style of encryption. I am wondering why A6 reports "active" without asking for a password. How could it decrypt things when ... the user didnt provide a password?

Comment: Without knowing about the specifics of how that tool generates its reports of active/not active, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Well, the app is called "API demo"; thus I kinda assume that it simply calls openly available Android APIs to demo their usage; so I guess it simply using some "default" path like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640708/check-if-android-filesystem-is-encrypted